# JSON file and execute javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, google-analytics

I have a `PHP` file that returns `JSON data`. But I want to execute some `javascript` (Google Analytics code)

Here's my code :

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: application/json');

   //GOOGLE ANALYTICS SCRIPT
   $js = "<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3', 'loopse.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

     </script>";

   echo $js;

   //some code to get data
   echo json_encode($data); 
?>
```

Everything works fine without js code, but i need to execute this js to track web services of my app.

--

**SOLUTION**

I found a solution by using Google Analytics with POST-Requests directly with php

Doc : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

Comment: Your not sending JSON, you're sending text/html

Comment: It looks like `ga('send', 'pageview');` will send you some formatted html and that will not mix well with your JSON you get from `$data`. Can you look at the page output without using AJAX to clarify this point?

Comment: Agreeing with Elias, here... JSON is really not the right tool for this job... just send text/plain.  You will insert it on the client side anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately data must be in JSON with http header application/json. I think this is the problem, I can't use `application/json` and run javascript code at the same time.
A working solution is to use `Google Analytics` with `Post-Requests` and send this request with PHP.
I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

For that to work, you will need to inject it into your page.

Assuming, of course, that you are pulling this specific code into a string 'result', you could do something like this:

```
var sTag = document.CreateElement('script');
sTag.innerHTML = result;
document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sTag);
```

Something like that ought to work for you.

Of course, you would pull the script tags out of the string you have listed above... otherwise, this would fail.

***EXPANDED***

OK, you seem to be of the mind that, by sending this from PHP, it should simply magically run when it gets to client side without any further client side changes.

This will never be the case.

When this 'code' gets to client side, client side will treat it as nothing more than a 'string'... because that is exactly what it is to the client.

Handling this exclusively by server-side code will not work.... the receiving web page has to cooperate with executing the code.

In the case of my code above, the **client** would take this data, and inject it into itself by creating a script element, and using this for the innerHTML of that script element.

The code sample above should be part of the web page which the client is already looking at when your code is sent to the browser.

Comment: The problem is that `javascript` doesn't run. Even if I write it with `echo` or directly at the end after `?>`

Comment: @RémiSantos Right... the code you see above?  Add that the the html page that the client is seeing.  This does not work at all if you are ONLY on server side.

Comment: @RémiSantos Expanded on my answer above.